# Getting SQLException Error in my Java program, not sure why

Tags: java, sql, database, exception, jdbc

I'm trying to have the code run when I click the button, however it's telling me I need to catch the exception, but I thought I already did. Am I missing something? It seems pretty simple but I can't seem to figure it out. **I am getting this error on lines, 76-83**

```
class EmpList { 

private static JFrame frame;
private static JTextField textField;

public static void main (String args []) 
  throws SQLException { 

DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

final String user, pass, query;

user = "asdf";
pass = "asdf";




query = "select * from customers";

try 
{

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
        ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@Picard2:1521:itec2",user,pass);
        final Statement stmt = conn.createStatement (); 
        final ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery (query);


        EmpList window = new EmpList();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 630, 470);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setBounds(10, 179, 594, 241);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(255, 69, 86, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblEnterCustomerId = new JLabel("Enter Customer ID (1-6)");
        lblEnterCustomerId.setBounds(240, 43, 153, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEnterCustomerId);

        JButton btnGetInfo = new JButton("Get Info");
        btnGetInfo.setBounds(255, 115, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnGetInfo);

        btnGetInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                while (rset.next ()) 
                    { 

                        textArea.append((rset.getString("CUSTID") + "  -  " + rset.getString("CUSTSSN")
                        + "  -  " + rset.getString("LNAME") + "  -  " + rset.getString("FNAME") + "  -  " +
                        rset.getString("STREET") + "  -  " + rset.getString("CITY") + "  -  " + rset.getString("STATE") +
                        "  -  " + rset.getString("ZIP") + "  -  " + rset.getString("PHONE") + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                        + System.getProperty("line.separator")));

                    }    


            }

        });


        window.frame.setVisible(true);


 }
```

I thought this would catch the exception, but I guess it doesn't.

```
 catch (SQLException e)
 {
    System.out.println ("Could not load the db"+e); 
 }

} 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `actionPerformed()` method has JDBC statements that might throw a `SQLException`.  You must handle the exception inside that method.  It's not covered by the `try` block in which you created the anonymous inner class.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much, completely missed that. I just added a try catch inside the actionperformed() method and it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant issue:

```
new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            while (rset.next ()) {...}
    }

}
```

This is a new class, and that function is calling rset from within a function context that does not have a try catch block for the enclosing context, AND does not throw exceptions from the function.

Change that code to whatever's appropriate but this will get you going :

```
new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            while (rset.next()) {...}
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
          // do something cool
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Catch clause also then it will definitely catch your exception.The exception thrown might not be an SQLException hence it is not caught

```
catch (Exception e)
 {
    System.out.println ("Exception Thrown: "+e); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be catching the Exception correctly. Are you sure you really have an SQL exception? You can also add this:

```
catch (Throwable t) {
   t.printStackTrace();
}
```

right after your catch block. And run your code again. This will catch whatever exception that is thrown and will print the stack trace.

But I bet you are already seeing that on your console, aren't you? Can you copy the stack trace as well?